# django: defining tags/filters/manager actions with less ceremony

Tags: python, django, django-1.7

To create custom `django` template tags and filters, as well as to add custom `manage.py` commands no matter how trivial, the docs tell you to create specific directory structures.

I'm working on a pretty tiny project, and it pains me to double the structural complexity of the application just to add a petite filter or command.

Is there any way of registering tags, filters and commands in a compact, straightforward manner? Imperatively wherever I want, rather than declaratively 2 levels down the directory hierarchy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although a bit hackish, it turned out to be perfectly possible for the tag/filter case. Commands, no: django actually searches the filesystem for the `.py` files involved.

The template hack is completely self-contained -- it won't leak dubious stuff into nearby code. A single module can hold all of the metamagic, and be imported by regular modules.

First, we have to create a mock module. We'll create a nice decorator to turn regular classes into modules:

```
def module(path):
    def decorator(cls):
        if '.' in path:
            parent_path, name = path.rsplit('.', 1)
            module(parent_path)(type(name, (object,), { name: cls }))

        return sys.modules.setdefault(path, cls)
    return decorator
```

Yes, the recursion is necessary (we need the full import path mocked) and it can be used to create a fake `templatetags` module like this:

```
@module('app.templatetags.extras')
class TemplateExtras(object):
    class register:
        tags    = {}
        filters = {}

# Optional: avoid using {% load %}:
django.template.libraries['app.templatetags.extras'] = TemplateExtras
django.template.base.add_to_builtins('app.templatetags.extras')
```

Add two more pretty decorators into the mix...

```
def templatetag(f):
    return TemplateExtras.register.tags.setdefault(f.__name__, f)

def templatefilter(f):
    return TemplateExtras.register.filters.setdefault(f.__name__, f)
```

... and you get the following clean, straightforward syntax:

```
# imported or present in app/__init__.py
@templatefilter
def datestr(date):
    return datetime.strftime(date, '%Y-%m-%d')
```